# Why do you use onPrepareOptionsMenu to create a menu where the layout file appears at the top of the screen but the runtime appears at the bottom?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a menu on my app's top like which showed me in the AS's xml, but in Android 6.0,it's on the bottom. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.
[image]

I have tried many methods like change my code, add the `android:showAsAction='always'`, but it doesn't work.
[image]

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_new_folder"
    android:title="@string/menu_create_folder" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_export_text"
    android:title="@string/menu_export_text"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_sync"
    android:title="@string/menu_sync"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_setting"
    android:title="@string/menu_setting" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create menu like this -

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_more"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_dots"
        android:title="more"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_new_folder"
    android:title="@string/menu_create_folder" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_export_text"
    android:title="@string/menu_export_text"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_sync"
    android:title="@string/menu_sync"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_setting"
    android:title="@string/menu_setting" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
</menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

And in your activity's onCreateOptionMenu add this -

```
menu.findItem(R.id.action_more).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
```